# Robot enter key not triggering code in JTextfield

Tags: java, jtextfield, enter, awtrobot

I have made a Hot Potato game and have made it so that by entering certain letter keys and pressing enter in a JTextfield, the other player gets a turn and the GUI updates. I would like to get the spacebar act as the "enter" button when the game is running before a timer runs out, and so I have looked into using a Robot to fire the enter key when pressing the space. It appears that it works as the , however for some reason when I use the space to enter the letter, it doesn't run the rest of the code attached to the ActionListener correctly.

Do I need to add some more code that fires some sort of action associated with pressing the enter button? Is there something more to the simulating the action of the enter key besides r.keyPress(keyCode)? Below I believe is all revenant code this part of the program.

```
public char l = 'a'; // char l acts as random char target
public String s = ""; // String s acts as target
boolean p1Starts = false;

int totalTime = 1000*(HotPotato.randNum()); // randomizing the length of the game
long startTimeMili = 100;  // setting up the current timer
long startTimeSec = 1;  // setting up the current timer
boolean timerState = true; // creating timer boolean
Robot r; 

JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel graphics = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));

public HotPotatoGUI() {

    myHotPotato = new HotPotato();

    setTitle("Hot Potato");

    // graphics = new JPanel();

    myPicture = new HotPotatoDrawer(myHotPotato.state());
    setContentPane(content);

    team1.addActionListener(this);
    main.addActionListener(this);
    team2.addActionListener(this);

    entryText.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){ 

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent a) {
             if(a.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                try {
                    r = new Robot();
                } catch (AWTException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 int keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_ENTER; // the enter key
                 r.keyPress(keyCode);
                 r.keyRelease(keyCode);

             }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    entryText.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

            String entry = entryText.getText(); // sets entry equal to text put into textfield

            System.out.print("\nQuestion " + s); // remove
            System.out.print("\nEntry " + entry); // remove

            if (entry.equals(s))
            {
                myHotPotato.flipSwitchOne();
                p1Starts = !p1Starts;
                l = HotPotato.randLetterBoth(p1Starts); // sets new char target 
                s = Character.toString(l); // converts new target into string
                long present = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis());

                // should activate when the timer reaches 0
                if (present - startTimeSec >= totalTime/1000) {
                    myHotPotato.endGame();
                    System.out.print("Switched");
                    entryText.removeActionListener(this);
                }

                // lines to see the variables involved in the timer
                System.out.print("\n + total time = " + totalTime/1000);
                //System.out.print("\n + currenttime = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                System.out.print("\n Timer " + (present - startTimeSec));
                System.out.print("\n + TimerState = " + myHotPotato.stateTimer());

                setLabels(s, p1Starts);
                myPicture.makeHotPotatoOn(myHotPotato.state());
                myPicture.repaint();

            }

            entryText.setText(""); // clears text after entry

            timerState = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeSec >= totalTime);

          }
        });
```

Output Text. Note how the Entry shows it is the same letter as the Question letter, but in the first case using "enter" used all of the code in my ActionListener, while the space key only seemed to execute the strings there.

```
Question c
Entry c
 + total time = 12
 Timer 2
 + TimerState = true
Question n
Entry n
```

Comment: what exactly should happen once you press enter? i dont think that you need a robot to emulate the enter key being pressed

Comment: Without seeing sample output it really hard to guess. The easy answer is move actionperformed() out of your listener and call it from both your action listener and your key listener instead of simulating a key press, but that assumes both work independently.

Comment: XtremeBaumer: I would like for the spacebar to act as enter here and after the spacebar is pressed, the JTextfield should take the letter entered and store it in a Stringe entry that will then be compared against a randomly generated one. If the two match, a new random letter will be generated and you will repeat the process.

Tosh: I have included some text from the console that displays when I use enter and then spacebar.